# Trick for listing authors

Tags: macros, titles

I wrote the following code:

```
\makeatletter
 \newtoks\author@toks\newcounter{author@counter}%
 \setcounter{author@counter}{0}%
 \newcommand{\authorAdd}[1]{%
 \ifnum\theauthor@counter>0\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks,    #1}%
 \else\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks\@author{#1}}%
 \fi\stepcounter{author@counter}%
 }
 \newcommand{\printauthor}{{\sc Authors:}\the\authors@toks}  
\makeatother
```

that is, I can add an author with the command `\authorAdd{}` and then the command `\printauthor` list all the author, separating them with a comma. I would like tu replace the last comma with the word "and". How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: You could make an optional argument, or starred variant, for `\authorAdd` to specify the last in the list.

Comment: Please do not use `\sc` -- that command is deprecated. Use `\scshape` or `\textsc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'traditional' way with the `\@elt` splitting feature:

Counter reset lists use the `\@elt` splitting, i.e. the counters that should be reset by `foo` counter are stored this way:

`foobar\@elt otherfoobar\@elt`. The list is named `cl@foo` and is called each time in stepping command, whereas `\@elt` is a 'volatile' macro, being defined to do some action.

The same approach can be applied here, using `\@elt` instead of `,` as name separator.

The `\printauthor` command just uses `\the\author@toks` and defines a special `\@elt` (in a group) that displays the correct `,` or `and` separator finally.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
 \newtoks\author@toks\newcounter{author@counter}%
 \setcounter{author@counter}{0}%
 \newcommand{\authorAdd}[1]{%
 \ifnum\theauthor@counter>0\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks\@elt\relax #1}%
 \else\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks\@author{#1}}%
 \fi\stepcounter{author@counter}%
 }

\newcounter{dummycounter}
\newcommand{\printauthor}{%
  \textsc{Authors:}%
  \begingroup
  \setcounter{dummycounter}{0}%
  \def\@elt##1{%
    \ifnum\c@dummycounter < \numexpr\c@author@counter - 2\relax%
    , 
    \else
    { and }%
    \fi
    \stepcounter{dummycounter}%
  }
  \the\author@toks%
  \endgroup
}



\makeatother

\begin{document}
\authorAdd{Shakespeare}
\authorAdd{Tolkien}
\authorAdd{Groucho Marx}
\authorAdd{Harpo Marx}
\authorAdd{Gummo Marx}
\authorAdd{Zeppo Marx}
\authorAdd{Chico Marx}

\printauthor
\end{document}
```

A `\clist` - splitting way with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}




\makeatletter
 \newtoks\author@toks\newcounter{author@counter}%
 \setcounter{author@counter}{0}%
 \newcommand{\authorAdd}[1]{%
 \ifnum\theauthor@counter>0\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks,    #1}%
 \else\author@toks=\expandafter{\the\author@toks\@author{#1}}%
 \fi\stepcounter{author@counter}%
 }
 \newcommand{\printauthor}{{\sc Authors:}\the\author@toks}  



\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{\splitauthorlist}[1]{%
  \clist_set:Nx \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist {,\space} {,\space} {\space and\space}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

 \newcommand{\printauthors}{%
   {\scshape Authors}:
   \splitauthorlist{\the\author@toks}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\authorAdd{Shakespeare}
\authorAdd{Tolkien}
\authorAdd{Groucho Marx}

\printauthors
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do a thing similar to the 'traditional' way around. The point is that I don't have to print the name of the author, but I have to store the list (the would-be-printed list: names, separated with commas and the word "end") in a token. How can I do?

Comment: @MaPo: I am not sure that I understand you in the full range. What's the purpose of `\printauthor` then? What should this list do then?

Comment: I'm trying to merge this issue to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307916/tricky-expansion-in-macro
but I'm not able to find how. I'll add a post here with my example code

Comment: @MaPo: That's another question again -- neither the `tricky expansion` nor this question should be edited. Use a new one and provide links to your questions

Comment: The new question is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307943/tricky-macro-expansion-and-list