# Tricky expansion in macro

Tags: macros, expansion

I wrote the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
 \newtoks\a@toks
 \newtoks\b@toks
 \newcounter{a@counter}%
 \newcounter{b@counter}%
 \setcounter{a@counter}{0}%
 \setcounter{b@counter}{0}%
 \newcommand{\aAdd}[1]{%
  \ifnum\thea@counter>0\a@toks=\expandafter{\the\a@toks {#1}}%
  \else\a@toks=\expandafter{\the\a@toks {#1}}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{a@counter}%
 }
 \newcommand{\reset}{%
  \setcounter{a@counter}{0}%
  \a@toks={}%
 }
 \newcommand{\bexp}{%
  \ifnum\theb@counter>0\b@toks=\expandafter{\the\b@toks, (\the\a@toks)}%
  \else\b@toks=\expandafter{\the\b@toks (\the\a@toks) }%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{b@counter}%
  \setcounter{a@counter}{0}%
  \a@toks=\noexpand{}%
 }
 \newcommand{\print}{%
  \the\b@toks%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
 Hello World!\\[3cm]
 \aAdd{a}
 \aAdd{b}
 \bexp
 \aAdd{c}
 \print
\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to do is the following: with `\aAdd` I add some element to a list, specifically in this example after

```
\aAdd{a}
\aAdd{b}
```

I expect `\a@toks` to be equal to `ab`. Then I flush this into another token, so I expect `\b@toks` to be equal to `ab`. The problem is when the command

```
\a@toks={}
```

is executed, this resets even `\b@toks` that continues to *follow* `\a@toks`, so that, when I execute

```
\aAdd{c}
```

`\b@toks` has the value `c`.

**I would like**, once set `\b@toks = \a@toks` to set only the value of `\b@toks`, so that, when I redefine `\a@toks`, `\b@toks` continues to have the preceding value (in this case `ab`).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: the question is very hard to understand, after the first two `\aAdd`  the register `\a@toks` is `{a}{b}` not `ab`  do you not want the braces? and after `\bexp` the register `\b@toks` is `(\the \a@toks ) ` but (I think?) you want the content of a@toks not a reference?

Comment: The problem is  not what is stored in `\a@toks`, but what is stored in`\b@toks`. I want that after I reset `\a@toks={}` in `\b@toks` continues to be `{a}{b}`. Have I explained it better?

Comment: beware doing `\ifnum\theb@counter>0\b@toks` which will try to expand  `\b@toks` to terminate the number before doing the test, it works here as `b@toks` is not expandable but safer to leave a space after `0` or better use `\z@`

Comment: `\b@toks=\expandafter{\the\a@toks}` for the first assignment?

Comment: but your description said a@toks contains `ab` which it does not, so the whole question is very confusing. b@toks is never set to {a}{b} in the above code.

Comment: Sorry if I confused `ab` with `{a}{b}`, let I will perform the following substitution in the question `ab` → `{a}{b}`. When `\b@toks=\expandafter{\the\b@toks (\the\a@toks)`} what is it stored in `\b@toks`? I would like to maintain this value even when, after I set `\a@toks={}`

Comment: b@toks is `(\the \a@toks ) ` as you have stored exactly that. not the expansion of a@toks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\expandafter` doesn't expand *everything* after it, just the following token. Also, since it seems like `b@counter` measures the content added to `\b@toks`, I don't see the need for

```
\ifnum...
\else\b@toks=\expandafter{\the\b@toks (\the\a@toks) }
\fi
```

where you want to add (an empty) `\b@toks` to itself.

The following produces what you're after, I think (I've cleaned it up a bit):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\a@toks
\newtoks\b@toks
\newcounter{b@counter}%
\newcounter{a@counter}[b@counter]%

\newcommand{\aAdd}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{a@counter}>0 \a@toks=\expandafter{\the\a@toks {#1}}%
  \else\a@toks=\expandafter{\the\a@toks {#1}}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{a@counter}%
}
\newcommand{\reset}{%
  \setcounter{a@counter}{0}%
  \a@toks={}%
}
\newcommand{\bexp}{%
  \ifnum\value{b@counter}>0
    \edef\x{\noexpand\b@toks={\the\b@toks, (\the\a@toks)}}%
  \else
    \edef\x{\noexpand\b@toks={(\the\a@toks)}}%
  \fi
  \x
  \stepcounter{b@counter}%
  \a@toks={}%
}
\newcommand{\print}{%
  \the\b@toks%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\bigskip

\aAdd{a}% \a@toks = {a}
\aAdd{b}% \a@toks = {a}{b}
\bexp% \a@toks = {}, \b@toks = {a}{b}
\aAdd{c}% \a@toks = {c}
\print% \b@toks

\end{document}
```

One could use

```
\b@toks=\expandafter{\expandafter(\the\a@toks)}
```

to make sure `\a@toks` is expanded before inserting it into `\b@toks`. However, I've instead opted to make sure everything expands before adding it to `\b@toks` by using an `\edef\x{...}\x` approach.

If leaving behind an unwanted `\x` is a problem, you can use the following definition for `\bexp`:

```
\newcommand{\bexp}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\value{b@counter}>0
    \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\b@toks={\the\b@toks, (\the\a@toks)}}%
  \else
    \edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\b@toks={(\the\a@toks)}}%
  \fi
  \x
  \stepcounter{b@counter}%
  \a@toks={}%
}
```

Comment: `\noexpand{` is harmless, but...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle... sorry, missed that one.

Comment: Just use e-TeX!

Comment: It is almost I like to do, the last thing is that I was lookin for. I still do not understand why, if between the `\aAdd{c}` and the `\print` i write another `\bexp` I get `(ab), ()` instead of `(ab), (c)`,which I would like to obtain for my purposes...

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand a bit more about token registers and such.  I've always been clueless on them.

Comment: @MaPo: My answer was updated to use an `\edef\x{...}\x` approach rather than `\b@toks=\expandafter{...}` as the former expands its entire contents, whereas the latter only expands the first token inside the group `{...}`. Based on that the output is `(ab), (c)` for `\aAdd{a} \aAdd{b} \bexp \aAdd{c} \bexp \print`.

Comment: You're leaving behind a definition for `\x`, which is not desirable.

Comment: @egreg: But not the end of the world...

Comment: @Werner Yes, it can be.

Comment: Is it possible even to eliminate the unwanted `\x`? To make the code safer?

Comment: @MaPo: I've added that at the end of my answer. You can create the `\edef\x` definition inside a group as I suggest. The `\endgroup` inside the definition for `\x` will destroy `\x` upon execution.

Answer (score 5):

Werner's analysis is very good. Here's an alternative implementation with `xparse` and `expl3`. Note that you can define as optional argument to `\print` the separator between items (default is “comma-space”).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\aAdd}{m}
 {
  \mapo_aadd:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\bexp}{}
 {
  \mapo_bexp:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\reset}{}
 {
  \mapo_reset:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\print}{O{,~}}
 {
  \mapo_print:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_mapo_a_tl
\seq_new:N \l_mapo_b_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mapo_aadd:n
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_mapo_a_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mapo_bexp:
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_mapo_b_seq { ( \exp_not:V \l_mapo_a_tl ) }
  \mapo_reset:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mapo_reset:
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_mapo_a_tl
 }
\cs_new:Nn \mapo_print:n
 {
  \seq_use:Nn \l_mapo_b_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent
Hello World!\\
\aAdd{a}\aAdd{b}\bexp\aAdd{c}%
\print\\
\bexp
\print[---]

\end{document}
```

[image]