# \clist and hyperref

Tags: macros, hyperref, expl3

using package `xparse` I stored the author of a certain paper in a `\clist` in the following way

```
\NewDocumentCommand\addauthor{m}{%                           
 \clist_put_right:Nn\l_allauthors{#1}%                       
}
```

and the I used in the pdf the command

```
\addauthor{bla bla bla}
```

to add some author. Then I also defined the function

```
\NewDocumentCommand \printall{}{
 \clist_use:Nnnn \l_allauthors{~and~}{,~}{~and~}
}
```

and `\printall` actually print al the author, as expected. The problem comes when I try to set

```
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\printall}}
```

I get the error message

```
Token not allowed in PDF string
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Untested: Try `\space` instead of `~`

Comment: I tried: id didn't work. Even if I replace, just for a try, `{ ~and~}{,~}{~and~}` with `{}{}{}`; same error.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307943/tricky-macro-expansion-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\printall` must be expanded first, i.e. use `pdfauthor=\expandafter{\printall}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_allauthors_clist

\NewDocumentCommand\addauthor{m}{%                           
  \clist_put_right:Nn\l_allauthors_clist{#1}%                       
}

\NewDocumentCommand \printall{}{
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_allauthors_clist {~and~}{,~}{~and~}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\addauthor{bla bla bla}
\addauthor{Gandalf}


\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\expandafter{\printall}}

\section{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you know that `pdfauthor=\expandafter{\printall}` works?

Comment: @Manuel: I looked into the `properties` of the pdf file.

Comment: Okey, I was more into the TeX part. Is that a feature of certain key-value packages?

Answer (score 3):

Change your code into

```
\clist_new:N \g_mapo_allauthors_clist

\NewDocumentCommand\addauthor{m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_mapo_allauthors_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \printall { } { } % initialization
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \printall { }
 {
  \clist_use:Nnnn \l_mapo_allauthors_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
 }
```

The main point is `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` (with a preventive check that the command is undefined). Macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are “protected”, so they won't expand in `\edef` contexts, which is what `hyperref` uses for getting the authors' list in `pdfauthor`. On the other hand, `\clist_use:Nnnn` is safely fully expandable, so we can (and should) use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Use the proper naming convention for variables: `g` stands for “global”, which should be used here as the author list seems better treated as global; next comes a prefix (the package name or the code author's name), then the actual name and finally the type of variable.

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_mapo_allauthors_clist

\NewDocumentCommand\addauthor {m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_mapo_allauthors_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \printall { } { } % initialization
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \printall { }
 {
  \clist_use:Nnnn \g_mapo_allauthors_clist { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\addauthor{Euclid}
\addauthor{Archimedes}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\printall}}

\section{Foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]